# Redirecting stdout and stderr together VS redirecting stdout and then stderr to stdout's file

Tags: shell, io-redirection

What is the difference between this redirection

```
some-program &> some_file
```

and this one?

```
some-program > some_file 2>&1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `bash` and `zsh` shells, there is no difference between the two.  The `&>file` redirection is syntactic sugar implemented as an extension to the POSIX standard that means exactly the same thing as the standard `>file 2>&1`.

Note that using the `&>` redirection in a script executed by a non-`bash`/`zsh` interpreter will likely break your script in interesting ways, as `&` and `>` would be interpreted independently of each other.

```
some_command &>file
```

would, in a non`-bash`/`zsh` script, be the same as

```
some_command & >file
```

and as

```
some_command &
>file
```

This starts `some_command` as a background job, and truncates/creates the file called `file`.

Also related:

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 4):

The second form [is POSIX-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_07), and will work in any POSIX shell.

The first form is exactly equivalent, but it will only work in shells that support the shortened form (Bash and Zsh, to name two), and will fail in others (Dash, for example, the `/bin/sh` implementation used in Debian and derivatives).

If portability is important, you should use the two-step form.