# POSIX compliant way to redirect stdout and stderr to a file

Tags: shell, io-redirection, posix, stdout, stderr

I am trying to write a script which is POSIX compliant, so it can run on any *nix system (Debian, Fedora, CentOS, AIX, Arch... ALL of them). When it comes to redirection, I am rather confused on what is supported by POSIX and what is not.

If I redirect `ls -l file missingfile &> out.txt` this works perfectly in `bash`. The line from `stderr` complaining that `missingfile` doesn't exist, and the permissions output from `file`, are both in `out.txt`. However, I believe this is only working because these shells support more than just POSIX standard operators. Upon researching this question I've come across conflicting answers.

[This stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/229446), for example, seems to imply that `&>`, `>&`, `>>&` and `&>>` are non-standard operations. However, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581511/229446) explicitly states that `some-program > some_file 2>&1` is POSIX compliant. Does this mean that the `>&` operator (using digits for `stderr` & `stdout`) is POSIX compliant whereas using `&>` to auto redirect both `stderr` and `stdout` to a file is **not** POSIX compliant? Or are both `&>` and `>&` not POSIX compliant / POSIX compliant (one of these two people are wrong)?

I considered just avoiding the `&` sign completely and using `ls -l file missingfile >out.txt 2>out.txt` however this comes with its own issue. Running the `ls` command this way causes the shell to open two file handles for `out.txt`, both pointing to offset 0 in the file. So when `ls` looks for these two files, one of the messages gets clobbered.

What one would expect `ls -l file missingfile >out.txt 2>out.txt` to output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 blah blah 0 Jun  3 13:18 file
ls: cannot access 'missingfile': No such file or directory
```

What is actually output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 blah blah 0 Jun  3 13:18 file
le or directory
```

What is the best way to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file in a POSIX compliant fashion?

Comment: I updated the misleading part of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/229446

Comment: `&> out.txt` doesn't work in Dash. It does in Busybox sh, though, along with Bash and Zsh.

Comment: @ilkkachu You are correct. I got confused on which shell I was using when I was testing it. I've updated my question

Comment: This isn't really about portability across operating systems, but portability across _shells_.  One can get variance in what provides the `sh` command even simply among versions of the same operating system in some cases.

Comment: There is a shell called `dash` which is meant _not_ to have any extension to POSIX standard. So if your script works in dash, it will work in bash, ksh, ash etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02). The language isn't always easy to follow, but if you know what you're looking for, you can see whether it's there or not.

POSIX includes the redirection operations `N>&word` and `N<&word` where *N* is an optional file descriptor number (defaulting to 0 for input and 1 for output) and *word* can be:

- A sequence of digits, to redirect file descriptor *N* to whatever is already open on *word*.
- The character `-`, to close file descriptor *N*.

So `>out.txt 2>&1` is a POSIX-compliant way to redirect both standard output and standard error to `out.txt`. It also works in pre-POSIX [Bourne shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/).

`>&` *followed by a file name* is an extension in some shells (including bash) that redirects both stdout and stderr to that file.

`&>` is a synonym of `>&` followed by a file name in bash (and zsh). It has the advantage of working even if the file name is a sequence of digits or `-` (for example `foo >&"$a"` is equivalent to `foo 1>&3 2>&1` if the value of `a` is the digit `3`, but to `foo >myfile 2>&1` if the value of `a` is `myfile`). Its downside is that it is incompatible with POSIX. In a POSIX-compliant shell, `echo foo &>bar` is parsed as the command `echo foo`, the `&` operator, and the command `>bar`: a background process that prints `foo`, and a foreground process that creates or empties the file `bar`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the POSIX-compliant way (`>file.txt 2>&1`) also works for Windows' command line. However, instead of `-` to close the file descriptor, you redirect to `nul` (same as `/dev/null`).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Watch out. Does redirection to `NUL` actually close the fd (thus return errors on I/O, like `2>-`), or just discard writes/return EOF on reads (like `2>/dev/null`)?

Comment: @TooTea As I said, you use `nul` to *redirect* the output stream, not to close it. `nul` is the same as `/dev/null`. From what I've seen, there's no file descriptor closing. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html <-- should give you a better light on what I mean

Comment: In the last paragraph, shouldn't it read `&> filename`?

Comment: @rexkogitans No, it's about `>&`, but I see how it could be hard to follow. I've reworded the last two paragraphs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about `-` - can I use `>-` in place of `>/dev/null`?

Comment: @Xerus Sometimes. It isn't the same thing, but in some circumstances it has the same effect. `>/dev/null` redirects the file descriptor whereas `>-` closes it. If the application tries to write and ignores write failures, this has the same effect. If the application exits on write failures, this likely doesn't have the same effect. If the application opens a file and it lands on that descriptor, this could have a completely different effect, e.g. ending up writing log messages to the file intended for normal output.