# &> is running the command in the background instead of redirecting stdout/err?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I'm looking at a pre-commit git hook script. Here's the part I'm struggling with:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
testcmd="go test -race ${godirs} "
failed=
${testcmd} &> /dev/null # problematic line
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    failed=1
    ${testcmd}
fi
```

`godirs` is a list of folders built earlier in the script. When I run this, I see the output of `testcmd` running slightly delayed (it prints over my next prompt). It seems that `&>` isn't redirecting 2 outputs. It's running the go test in the background and not even redirecting output.

I'm no good at shell scripting. I know I could rewrite it as `> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` but this is a learning opportunity. How can I fix this so I can still use `&>`?

Comment: `&>` (as a redirection) is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) - either change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash` or use the POSIX `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @steeldriver That sounds like a legitimate answer. You should post it.

Comment: as an aside: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: Gilles's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590707/170373) also has the explanation of how `&>` is interpreted in a POSIX shell, at the very end.