# When redirecting error to sto, should the command comes after the file or before?

Tags: io-redirection

Are there any differences among three commands below?

1. `some_command >> $logfile 2>&1`
2. `some_command 2>&1 >> $logfile`
3. `( some_command ) >& $logfile`

I originally just logged like `mysqldump ${OPTIONS} >> $logfile` which didn't leave `disk full` erorrs on the log.
Will all 3 commands above will leave errors on the logfile? How are they different?

Comment: @muru could you explain the 3rd option? Does creating subshell process automatically does `2&>1`?

Comment: The subshell is irrelevant there anyway, you should use `some_command &> "$log_file"`. It's the `&>`/`>&` that does the equivalent of `>file 2>&1`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581510/70524